# How to pass arguments to a script that were generated by another script

Tags: shell-script, perl, arguments, output

I have the following scenario.

I have a Perl script that takes an ID and looks up some arguments from a DB.
lets say `look_up_args.pl 234` prints the following `abc 123 "something with spaces"`

I have another shell script `script.sh` that does the following

`some_command --param1 $1 --param2 $2 --par3 "$3" ...`

what I am trying to do is to call the script with the arguments

I have tried the following 2 methods

```
./script.sh `./look_up_args.pl 234`
./script.sh $(./look_up_args.pl 234)
```

still whenever I run the `script.sh`, `$3` seems to contain only  `"something"` causing my script to fail. I am looking for away to pass the quoted string with out any form of shell expansion/etc... The third parameter may contain other special bash characters, but will always be quoted.

Comment: To avoid the comedy of errors that is posix shell word splitting, another option might be (the comedy of errors that is) JSON or something via standard I/O `lookupargs 234 | thenextthing`

Comment: While this is probably a better way of doing this. Its just seems overly complex for a simple problem. All I am trying to do is to run a command with some arguments stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this, but try:

```
eval "./script.sh $(./look_up_args.pl 234)"
```

This should work, but keep in mind that `eval` will evaluate whatever `look_up_args.pl` happens to output, meaning you leave yourself vulnerable to code injection.

A better option would be what @thrig suggested in the comments: use a standardized data format to pass data between tools.  Even a newline-delimited string would be a fine format for a shell-style processing pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, eval seems to have done the trick. This isn't production code, so I can live with the security risk. Still there should be a way to just escape the arguments somehow.

Comment: Assuming you control the output of `look_up_args.pl`, it's not so much a security risk as it is a stability risk.  Unexpected and unpredictable behavior is the major concern.

Comment: Yeh, I understand that. I was just hoping not to have to change `script.sh` since I already call that from elsewhere. I can modify the Perl script anyway I want thought.